# Display related posts randomly that match "any" existing tags?

Tags: posts, tags

I would like to ask that what code should i add in order to make my related posts by tag to display randomly? I got this code from somewhere else.

```
<?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="related"><h4>Related Posts</h4>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="ncc">
<h5><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

</div><!--ncc-->

<? }
echo '</div><!--related-->';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: I just need to know how to exclude one tag

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98024/related-posts-by-multiple-tags

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395419/display-related-post-based-on-tag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some of the code in OP is a bit old and depreciated, like `caller_get_posts` which was depreciated years ago. The correct parameter to use now is `ignore_sticky_posts`. Your query is also really inefficient and not good for performance.

Here is how I would tackle this issue

- Use `get_queried_object_id()` to get the current post ID instead of the more unreliable method using the global `$post`
- Use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to return all the tag ID's assigned to the post. From what I make, we only need to get ID's, and not the complete tag objects
- Use a proper [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to get all posts that have any of these tags attached to them. This is more personal preference as it is easy to change across taxonomies and also, looking at source code, the tag parameters use a `tax_query`
- Use `rand` as value to the [`orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) parameter in `WP_Query`

In short, putting this all in code: (*Untested, requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
<?php
$tags = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'post_tag', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
$args = [
    'post__not_in'        => array( get_queried_object_id() ),
    'posts_per_page'      => 5,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'orderby'             => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms'    => $tags
        ]
    ]
];
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div id="related"><h4>Related Posts</h4>';
        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="ncc">

                <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div><!--ncc-->
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '</div><!--related-->';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Peter Goosen, amazing! Your code works well! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)

Comment: wow looks great . another question : how we exclude most popular posts from this query ? Post wievs stored in custom field name called (pageView) ? is that possible ?

Comment: Still works well in PHP 8... it's that Goosen quality ;)

Comment: I can't edit currently, but I'm leaving a note here that the `rel="nofollow"` snippet should be deleted from this answer.