# get_queried_object_id / short code returning blank

Tags: shortcode

From [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183498/3206), I'm using the following in a small custom plugin:

```
function mm_related_posts() {

    if (is_singular()) {
        $related_posts = '';
        $tags = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'post_tag', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
        $args = [
            'post__not_in'        => array( get_queried_object_id() ),
            'posts_per_page'      => 5,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'terms'    => $tags
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $related_posts = '<div id="related"><h4>Related Posts</h4>';
                while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post();
                    $related_posts .= '<div class="ncc"><h5><a href="' . the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . the_title() . '" rel="nofollow">' . the_title() . '</a></h5>' . the_excerpt() . '</div><!--ncc-->';
                wp_reset_postdata();
                $related_posts .= '</div><!--related-->';
            }
        }
        return $related_posts;
    }
}

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('mm_related_posts', 'mm_related_posts');
```

However, the shortcode `[mm_related_posts]` is not outputting any content.

Can you see what is wrong with this code, please?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Remember what Uncle Wapuu always says: "shortcodes should return their markup as a string, not echo it."

Comment: Thank you @bosco, I've changed my code, but the issue remains.

Comment: @Steve can you check your wp-admin have you added any tags in posts ?
If yes can you check $tags has any value and then check   $my_query->found_posts has any value.

Comment: Thanks, @Prits, originally I didn't have any tags on posts. I have added `display` as a tag to 2 posts, and I see `$tags` = `display`, and `$my_query->found_posts` = `1`. However, `$related_posts .= '<div class="ncc"><h5><a href="' . the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . the_title() . '" rel="nofollow">' . the_title() . '</a></h5>' . the_excerpt() . '</div><!--ncc-->';` is still outputting HTML with no variables output.

Comment: i.e. there is no content between the tags

Answer (score 0):

This code doesnt return anything if the shortcode isnt place on a singular page, also if placed in a singular page and that singular page post has no tags associated will return false, and also if it is on a post with tags associated and the tags are not in more posts also returns empty.

After testing the code, it works if the shortcode is placed in a singular page like for example in a post.  but the post has to have tags, and that tags need to be also in others posts.  then it will work.
I have notice also that the related posts are needing some css to have a better look, but that can depends on the theme.
This code works fine when placed in a singular post page, that has tags associated.
However the code is not prepare to not have any tag on the post that is in, and show random related.

Comment: I placed the shortcode in a Beaver Builder Themer template used by a specific category of posts. On one of those posts, no content is displayed. If I edit that specific post in Gutenberg and add a Shortcode block with the shortcode `[mm_related_posts]`, nothing is displayed still.