# How to display related posts from this code?

Tags: tags

I have two scripts to display related posts that fit my terms, but I don't know how to call them, please help me. I found this code [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98024/related-posts-by-multiple-tags).

**Related Posts 1:**

```
function get_pew_related_data($args, $post_id, $related_id) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    $post_id = intval( $post_id );
    if( !$post_id && $post->ID ) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    if( !$post_id ) {
        return false;
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'topics',
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'max' => 5
    );
    $options = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $transient_name = 'pew-related-' . $options['taxonomy'] . '-' . $post_id;

    if( isset($_GET['flush-related-links']) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<p>Related links flushed! (' . $transient_name . ')</p>';
        delete_transient( $transient_name );
    }

    $output = get_transient( $transient_name );
    if( $output !== false && !is_preview() ) {
        //echo $transient_name . ' read!';
        return $output;
    } 

    $args = array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $orig_terms_set = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $options['taxonomy'], $args );

    //Make sure each returned term id to be an integer.
    $orig_terms_set = array_map('intval', $orig_terms_set);

    //Store a copy that we'll be reducing by one item for each iteration. 
    $terms_to_iterate = $orig_terms_set;

    $post_args = array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_type' => $options['post_type'],
        'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
        'posts_per_page' => 50
    );
    $output = array();
    while( count( $terms_to_iterate ) > 1 ) {

        $post_args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $options['taxonomy'],
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $terms_to_iterate,
                'operator' => 'AND'
            )
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $post_args );

        /*
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo $wpdb->last_query;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Terms: ' . implode(', ', $terms_to_iterate);
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Posts: ';
        echo '<br>';
        print_r( $posts );
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        */

        foreach( $posts as $id ) {
            $id = intval( $id );
            if( !in_array( $id, $output) ) {
                $output[] = $id;
            }
        }
        array_pop( $terms_to_iterate );
    }

    $post_args['posts_per_page'] = 10;
    $post_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $options['taxonomy'],
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $orig_terms_set
        )
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $post_args );

    foreach( $posts as $count => $id ) {
        $id = intval( $id );
        if( !in_array( $id, $output) ) {
            $output[] = $id;
        }
        if( count($output) > $options['max'] ) {
            //We have enough related post IDs now, stop the loop.
            break;
        }
    }

    if( !is_preview() ) {
        //echo $transient_name . ' set!';
        set_transient( $transient_name, $output, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    return $output;
}

function pew_related( $args = array(), $post_id = '', $related_id = '' ) {
    $post_ids = get_pew_related_data( $args, $post_id, $related_id );

    if( !$post_ids ) {
        return false;
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'posts_per_page' => min( array(count($post_ids), 10)),
        'related_title' => 'Related Posts'
    );
    $options = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $related_posts = new WP_Query( $options );
    if( $related_posts->have_posts() ):
    ?>
    <h5><?=$options['related_title']?></h5>
    <div id="related-material" class="promo">
        <?php while ( $related_posts->have_posts() ):
            $related_posts->the_post();
        ?>
            <a class="post" href="<?=the_permalink();?>">
                <div class="meta">
                    <?php
                    $post_project = wp_get_object_terms($related_posts->post->ID, 'projects');
                    $project = 'Pew Research Center';
                    $project_slug = '';
                    if( isset($post_project[0]) ) {
                        $project = $post_project[0]->name;
                        $project_slug =  $post_project[0]->slug;
                    } elseif( $related_posts->post->post_type == 'fact-tank' ) {
                        $project = 'Fact Tank';
                        $project_slug = 'fact-tank';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <span class="project <?=$project_slug;?> right-seperator"><?=$project;?></span>
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?></span>
                </div>
                <h2><?=the_title();?></h2>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

         ?> 
    </ol>
    </div>
    <?php
    endif;

}
```

**Related Posts 2:**

```
function exe_get_related_posts_by_common_terms( $post_id, $number_posts = 0, $taxonomy = 'post_tag', $post_type = 'post' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = (int) $post_id;
    $number_posts = (int) $number_posts;

    $limit = $number_posts > 0 ? ' LIMIT ' . $number_posts : '';

    $related_posts_records = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT tr.object_id, count( tr.term_taxonomy_id ) AS common_tax_count
             FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr
             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr2 ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id
             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id
             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as p ON p.ID = tr.object_id
             WHERE
                tr2.object_id = %d
                AND tt.taxonomy = %s
                AND p.post_type = %s
             GROUP BY tr.object_id
             HAVING tr.object_id != %d
             ORDER BY common_tax_count DESC" . $limit,
            $post_id, $taxonomy, $post_type, $post_id
        )
    );

    if ( count( $related_posts_records ) === 0 )
        return false;

    $related_posts = array();

    foreach( $related_posts_records as $record )
        $related_posts[] = array(
            'post_id' => (int) $record->object_id,
            'common_tax_count' => $record->common_tax_count
        );

    return $related_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options on how to use the functions you've found. The first one is to add one of the functions to your single post template file.

```
pew_related( 
  array(), // add custom parameter key=>value pairs, if needed
  get_the_ID(), 
  '' // not sure what is the purpose of the third parameter 
);
```

or

```
$related_posts = exe_get_related_posts_by_common_terms( get_the_ID(), 3, 'post_tag', 'post' );
if ( $related_posts ) {
  // foreach loop the $related_posts array for desired html output
}
```

The second option is to hook one of functions to suitable action or filter. For example,

```
// functions.php
add_filter( 'the_content', function($content){
  if ( ! is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    return $content;
  }
  ob_start(); // push html output to buffer
  pew_related( 
    array(), // add custom parameter key=>value pairs, if needed
    get_the_ID(), 
    '' // not sure what is the purpose of the third parameter 
  ); 
  $related_html = ob_get_clean(); // get buffer content
  return $related_html ? $content . $related_html : $content; // concat html to post content
} );
```

Comment: Hi @Antti Can you tell me the script is complete with html?

Comment: @RenomuReza `pew_related()` looks like it spits out some html, but for the second one you'll need to write your own html. But in any case, If I were you, I wouldn't just copy-paste the codes as is, but instead I'd tweak and modify them to fit my exact setup.