# Get related posts matching most of the provided tags using WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, tags

I need help in getting related posts using multiple tags.

I have posts with the tags `poetry`, `motivational`, `attitude`, `rules`, `lines`, `sigma` and `inspirations`.

I want related posts matching most of these tags using `WP_Query`.

> **Note:** each post doesn't have all of these tags.

Comment: You can either find posts that have any of those tags ***or*** posts that have all of those tags. Getting posts with "most" of those tags or sorting posts based on the number of matching tags is beyond the capabilities of WP_Query.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98024/related-posts-by-multiple-tags

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183494/related-posts-display-randomly-by-tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Related Posts by Multiple Tags?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98024/related-posts-by-multiple-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way of getting posts matching **most of these tags** using `WP_Query`.

### The usual documented methods:

If you want posts matching any of these tags, you may use:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tag_slug__in' => array( 'poetry', 'motivational', 'attitude', 'rules', 'lines', 'sigma', 'inspirations' )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Also, if you want posts matching all of these tags, you may use:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tag_slug__and' => array( 'poetry', 'motivational', 'attitude', 'rules', 'lines', 'sigma', 'inspirations' )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### Getting posts with most of these tags:

To achieve what you want, you'll have to either use a custom SQL query or some advanced customizations to the `WP_Query` generated SQL query using hooks.

For example, you may use the `posts_clauses` hook combined with `pre_get_posts` hook to alter the SQL generated by `WP_Query`.

To get posts with **most of these tags**, you'll need to include `count( wp_term_relationships.object_id)` in `SELECT` portion of the generated SQL query, and then sort the query result by that count in descending order.

The following is the code of a complete plugin that implements this logic:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: @fayaz.dev Related posts by most tags
 * Description: Show related posts by of the provided tags
 * Author: Fayaz Ahmed
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author URI: https://fayaz.dev/
 **/

namespace Fayaz\dev;

/**
 * Any WP_Query where 'order_by_most_tags' is set as an argument,
 * will be altered by this function, so that the query result is 
 * ordered by the number of matching tags in descending order.
 * However, if no matching tag is provided, then that query will not
 * be altered by this.
 */
function filter_posts_by_most_tags( $query ) {
    if( isset( $query->query['order_by_most_tags'] )
        && isset( $query->query_vars['tag_slug__in'] ) && ! empty( $query->query_vars['tag_slug__in'] ) ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_clauses', '\Fayaz\dev\add_select_count_tags', 10, 2 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', '\Fayaz\dev\filter_posts_by_most_tags' );

function add_select_count_tags( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // database query modification needed for ordering based on most tags
    $clauses['fields'] = $clauses['fields'] . ', count( ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '.object_id ) as number_of_tags';
    $clauses['orderby'] = 'number_of_tags DESC, ' . $clauses['orderby'];

    // we only need this once, so it's better to remove the filter after use
    remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', '\Fayaz\dev\add_select_count_tags', 10, 2 );
    return $clauses;
}
```

### Sample Plugin Usage:

The above plugin implements a custom `WP_Query` argument named `order_by_most_tags`. When it's set, the plugin will alter the result to get posts with most of the provided tags.

One you activate the plugin, use the code as shown below in your currently active theme's template files (e.g. `single.php`):

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tag_slug__in' => array( 'poetry', 'motivational', 'attitude', 'rules', 'lines', 'sigma', 'inspirations' ),
    'order_by_most_tags' => 1,
    // other order by (in case there are multiple matches with most tags)
    'orderby' => array( 'comment_count' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'ASC' )
);
$post_ID = get_the_ID();
if( $post_ID ) {
    // exclude current post
    $args['post__not_in'] = array( $post_ID );
}
echo '<h2>Related Posts</h2>';
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul';
}
else {
    echo '<h2>Nothing is found</h2>';
}
// Restore original Post Data, needed if this was run in a loop
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This is a what I want but I need a little bit more help?

Comment: This returns most of the Tag matched perfectly but What If some post matched 2, 2 tags and I want to change these 2,2 tags matched post order too.i.e order by date or views count desc or asc order?

Comment: Please read the `WP_Query` documentation. You can use order by date directly in `WP_Query`. This will be added with the other `order` and `orderby` you provide in the `$args`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional `orderby`. `date` is supported by `WP_Query` by default, There are many other supported `orderby` values. However, WordPress doesn't implement **view count** by default. So that is a completely separate question. So it cannot be discussed in this question.

Comment: Great answer @Fayaz! BTW, I think it could be even more beautiful, if instead of `order_by_most_tags` argument, you could implement it using the `order` and `orderby` arguments. In that case, we could use it like `'orderby' => array( 'most_tags' => 'DESC', 'comment_count' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'ASC' )`.  Please don't bother if it is too much additional work. I think the solution is already excellent.

Comment: Hmm, good idea! I'll play with it when I get time.

Comment: Fantastic stuff, but I'm not sure why you would limit the tags used? Why not remove that entire `'tag_slug__in'` array and auto-calculate? I suppose because the results are then less predictable, but you're trying to avoid multiple queries? In my case, I opted for a simpler solution, since the auto-calculated results were similar.